# Youtube videos keep playing in background when view disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my app I'm playing youtube videos using the following code:

```
_videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:_selectedVideo.video_id];
[_videoPlayerViewController presentInView:self.videoView];
[_videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer play];
```

Problem is when user clicks on play button, video is still loading and user press the back button then video starts playing in background. You can hear video sound in background. I have tried to stop the video in `viewDidDisappear` using below code:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

   if ([_selectedVideo.video_host isEqualToString:@"www.youtube.com"] ||     [_selectedVideo.video_host isEqualToString:@"youtu.be"])
{

    [_videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer stop];
    _videoPlayerViewController = nil;
}
}
```

It still doesn't work. This problem only happens when user change the view and video is still loading (not playing).

Comment: does it go in the if condition ?

Comment: yes and it works when video is playing

Comment: can you add a notification to listen to when video has started ?

Comment: So you're suggesting that I need MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange notification and when user change the view I can add a check and stop the video when the notification fire. Right?